# $E(X|Y)=0$ and $E(X|Z)=0$ imply $E(X|Y,Z)=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is it true that
$$
E(X|Y)=0\quad\text{and}\quad E(X|Z)=0
$$
imply $E(X|Y,Z)=0$? From iterated expectations, I understand that $E(X|Y,Z)=0$ implies both $E(X|Y)=0$ and $E(X|Z)=0$ but I don't know how to think about it in the reverse direction.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but does $E(X|Y) = E(X|Y\land (Z \lor \neg Z))$ ?

Comment: @davcha These are random variables, not propositions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: assume that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, non Dirac, centered, and consider $$X=YZ.$$ Then $E(X\mid Y)=YE(Z)=0$ and $E(X\mid Z)=ZE(Y)=0$ while $E(X\mid Y,Z)=X$.

Comment: thanks Did and thanks for your comments on the other answer. I need to study this subject more for sure.